# why can't bind be turned into function?

Tags: c++

the problem is that IDE says the bind cannot be turn into function pointer.

```
Fudge<int> obj(1);

std::function<void(std::vector<int>&)> a = std::bind(&Fudge<int>::_pack_method, obj); //IDE warning here
```

where the _pack_method is declared as

```
template <class E>
class Fudge
{
public:
 Fudge() = delete;
 Fudge(int i) {};
 void _pack_method(std::vector<E>& frames) {return;};
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem here is you are not accounting for the function parameter of `_pack_method`.  You need to tell `bind` how to fully bind with the function and you don't do that, you only give it the object to call the function on and not the vector parameter that it takes.  To fix this, you either need to provide the vector you want to pass to the member function like

```
std::bind(&Fudge<int>::_pack_method, obj, my_vector);
```

or you need to use a placeholder to tell `bind` that that the function object that is created needs to take in parameter in order for it to work.  That would look like

```
std::bind(&Fudge<int>::_pack_method, obj, std::placeholders::_1);
```

---

Instead of using `bind`, you could use a [lambda expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) which I find to be more explicit in denoting what is going on.  That would look like:

```
auto a = [&obj](std::vector<int>& var){ obj._pack_method(var); };
```

Comment: bind works with auto, but not with std::function. I have tried it.

std::function<void(std::vector<int>&)> a = std::bind(&Fudge<int>::_pack_method, obj, std::placeholders::_1); //IDE warning here

I am using Visual Studio 2017

Comment: @jojo_Aero_smith_the_dummy Is `std::function<void(std::vector<int>&)> a = std::bind(&Fudge<int>::_pack_method, obj, std::placeholders::_1);` not working for you?  It works fine here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a04e112e52be4130